# GNU make - prune output to equal a lower level of debugging (or two debug outputs)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know about `make --debug=[options]`.

[Make debug output](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html)

When I build normally, I have `--debug=vjm` but when this isn't very human readable; it has many `pruning [some file].h` lines

Is there a way to post-process this output to have a lower level of debug

**OR**

output two debug levels to two different files?

Comment: I can't help but ask why, do you need to debug your makefiles so often that this is an issue?

Comment: @user657267 inherited a project from a different company, probably have to refactor makefiles.

Comment: I'd say just `sed` the output to strip the lines you don't want to see.

Comment: @user657267 what about outputting two sets of debug levels?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, at least not without running make twice.

Comment: make doesn't support that sort of post-processing itself. Use some other tool. If you just want to ignore `pruning` lines that's simple enough with `sed`/`grep`/`awk`/etc. If you need something more complicated then show the actual output and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: @EtanReisner ok. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control over make's debug output is controlled by the flag you mentioned. It doesn't support being told to output at a certain level but then not show all the info at that level.

If you don't want some of the information then you get to not include that flag when you run make.

If, and I haven't looked recently, there's information output by `v` that isn't in `b` *other* than the `pruning` lines you don't want then you get to post-process to remove the `pruning` lines with something like `grep`/`sed`/`awk`/etc.

```
make --debug=vjm | grep -v '\<pruning\>'
```

or

```
make --debug=vjm | sed '/\<pruning\>/d'
```

or

```
make --debug=vjm | awk '!/\<pruning\>/'
```

etc.

If you need post-processing more complicated than simply dumping the `pruning` lines then you get to look into a fancier `awk`/etc. script.